# Inserting select into array Angular-Schema-Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-schema-form

I am trying to make an array, where each element contains select. My code right now:

```
angular.module('MaterialAidForm', ['schemaForm']).controller('FormController', function($scope) {
$scope.schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Comment",
  "required": [
    "comments"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "comments": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "spam": {
                "title": "Spam",
                "type": "select",
                "titleMap":
                {
                    "a": "A",
                    "b": "B"
                }
            }            
        },
        "required": [
          "name",
          "comment"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};

$scope.form = ["*"];
$scope.model = {};
});
```

But when I open browser, I only see array without selector inside.